# handle http_erros when posting with guzzle

Tags: php, phpunit, guzzle

I am trying to test a function that when called, returns error 500 from the server. i was able to do the same when using `get` like this:

```
    public function testApiAd_idNotExists(){
                $path = '/adserver/src/public/api/ad/98765432123456789';
                $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://10.0.0.37']);
                $response = $client->get($path, ['http_errors' => false]);
                $err = $response->getStatusCode();

                $this->assertEquals($err, 404);
    }
```

but when i tried doing the same with post it didn't work. In the guzzle documentation i cant find anything about `http_errors` and posting.
this is my attempt which is not working:

```
    public function testApiAd_postIllegalProviderId(){
            $client = new Client();
            $url = 'http://10.0.0.38/adserver/src/public/api/ad';

            $response = $client->post($url, ['form_params' => [
                                             'name' => 'bellow content - guzzle testing',
                                             'widget_id' => '1010101010',
                                             ]],['http_errors' => false]);

            $err = $response->getStatusCode();
            $this->assertEquals($err, 500);
    }
```

any idea how can i do that?? thx!